# How to remove multiple options in a select tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete two options from a select tag using jQuery using the following code

```
 $("#selectionid option[value='option1']").remove();
 $("#selectionid option[value='option2']").remove();
```

Is there any way to delete the two options at a time dynamically.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single line you can remove like

```
$('#selectionid option').filter('[value="option1"],[value="option2"]').remove();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unm05j78/1/)**

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
$("#selectionid option[value='option1'], #selectionid option[value='option2']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wildcard selectors?  I believe it'd be something like:

```
$("#selectionid option[value*='option']").remove();
```

Comment: In this case option with `value='option3'` will got remove also, and all which value starting from `option`

Comment: True.  This assumes only two elements: option1 & option2

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this line to delete both:

```
$("#selectionid option[value='option1'], #selectionid option[value='option2']").remove();
```

Or you could use this bind to display everything expect for the ones you want 'deleted'.

```
var list = ["option1", "option2"];
$('select option').filter(function () {
   return $.inArray(this.value, list) !== -1
}).remove();
```

[**`Example (JSFiddle)`**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2bEq/49/)