# Hide an option in a multiple select, when a specific option has been selected from another select

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have seen questions similar to this but mine is different.
so I have these first 2 dropdown menu (data are selected from my database) and another dropdown which is attributed with `multiple`,
now my code works on the first 2 dropdowns but when it comes to the `multiple` dropdown it's not working.

here are my dropdown menu;

```
<select class="custom-select" name="option_one">
 <option>test1</option>
 <option>test2</option>

<select class="custom-select" name="option_two">
 <option>test1</option>
 <option>test2</option>

<select id="multiple" class="custom-select" name="option_three[]" multiple="multiple">
 <option>test1</option>
 <option>test2</option>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function intializeSelect() {
  $('.custom-select').each(function(box) {
   var value = $('.custom-select')[box].value;
   if (value) {
    $('.custom-select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
   }
  });
};
 intializeSelect();
 $('.custom-select').on('change', function(event) {
  $('.custom-select').find('option').show();
 });
});
```

Comment: I've attempted to fix your indenting, but there's a missing `}`, so unclear exactly what your code is supposed to be.  Unlikely that's it's recursive without a start, so guessed on the indentation.  Please update, ideally with a complete snippet `[<>]` that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229858/how-to-remove-multiple-options-in-a-select-tag-using-jquery#:~:text=%24(%22%23selectionid%20option%5Bvalue,remove()%3B

Comment: @freedomn-m done editing

Comment: None of your options (as provided) have a value, so `$('.custom-select')[box].value` is always blank.   Please see about a [mcve] snippet.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that fixes the two things: no values / not calling init from the change event (though unclear if that's a mistake or not).   It's unclear what you're *trying* to achieve with this, other than "it works for 2" and "it doesn't work for 3".  What, in your requirement, is "working"?   Anyway, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/52gcohmk/

Comment: *The question should be updated to include **desired behaviour** (not just "so it works"), a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: @freedomn-m the value is the ID of whatever is selected on the dropdown from my database

Comment: Which isn't included in the question, or even mentioned.  Apologies, I forgot my mind-reading-cap this morning.  Please review [ask] and [mcve] with emphasis on *complete*, along with a *clear* statement of the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

With a single on change attached to all select , you could check  value and hide depending on innerHtml or value ( in your case no value , so checking by text) ,

What I've done is first showing all option , then check value if not undefined ,
if thre were a value hide other options input , that has same text value ,

See below working snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.custom-select').on('change', function(event) {
      let value = $(this).val();
      // show all options of all select
      $('.custom-select').find("option").show();
      // reset values after change of other select
      $('.custom-select').not(this).val("");

      if (value.length > 0) {
        $('.custom-select')
          .not(this)
          .find("option")
          .filter(function() {
            return $(this).html() == value;
          }).hide();

    };

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select" name="option_one">
  <option></option>
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
</select>
<select class="custom-select" name="option_two">
  <option></option>
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
</select>
<select id="multiple" class="custom-select" name="option_three[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I copied the code and it still does not work on me @Spring

Comment: @AZUREKNIGHT could you described what you need exactly ? if option selected in one select you should hide it in others ? whether it's multiple or not ?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i need, i'm having difficulties in hiding the selected options when it comes to the multiple select